# Kinect intrinsic calibration for skeleton tracking

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk, camera-calibration, kinect.toolbox

I am working on 3d Skeleton tracking using Kinect. I had one question about the Kinect calibration. I use Kinect SDK for skeleton tracking but when it is projected on screen I see the skeleton joints are deviating from its actual position. I had a doubt if I could adjust the focal length and intrinsic parameters of the Kinect it would map the skeleton accurately is that correct?

Comment: Can you share the portion of code in which you projected the skeleton?

Comment: Do you use kinect v2 or kinect v1?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to map the skeleton joints' coordinates into color/depth space.

Try this code:

```
private Point BodyToColorPoint(Joint joint)
    {
        // 3D space point
        CameraSpacePoint jointPosition = joint.Position;

        // 2D space point
        Point point = new Point();

        //you need to change the Image and Canvas dimensions
        //because the resolution of Kinect2 color camera is 1920 X 1080 (too big for my screen)
        //if your canvas size is 960 X 540, should dived point.X and point.Y by 2
        if (_mode == CameraMode.Color)
        {
            ColorSpacePoint colorPoint = this.kinectSensor.CoordinateMapper.MapCameraPointToColorSpace(jointPosition);

            point.X = float.IsInfinity(colorPoint.X) ? 0 : colorPoint.X;
            point.Y = float.IsInfinity(colorPoint.Y) ? 0 : colorPoint.Y;
        }
        else if (_mode == CameraMode.Depth || _mode == CameraMode.Infrared) 
        {
            DepthSpacePoint depthPoint = this.kinectSensor.CoordinateMapper.MapCameraPointToDepthSpace(jointPosition);

            point.X = float.IsInfinity(depthPoint.X) ? 0 : depthPoint.X;
            point.Y = float.IsInfinity(depthPoint.Y) ? 0 : depthPoint.Y;
        }
        return point;
    }
```